# Website hosted on S3 just downloads a blank file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an extremely simple website, literally just an HTML file with some text in it. I configured my bucket for hosting and set the homepage to index.html. I set the permissions per the AWS tutorial here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

For some reason, when I hit the website endpoint, Chrome is prompted to save a file called "download". If I save the file and open it, it is just blank, zero bytes. Why is my index.html file not served up?

UPDATE: I fixed the empty file issue, but it still wants to download my page instead of open it in the browser...

FIXED: The content-type was set incorrectly. When uploading the file, I had to explicitly the set the content type property to text/html or text/css.

Answer (score 7):

You need to set the Metadata properly - `content-type` as `text/html` for your html pages. Once this is through the browser would start to render the pages in the browser rather than downloading them.

Answer (score 5):

For those who are wondering how to fix the empty file issue when hitting the cloudfront url. I had forgotten to add a default root object and (maybe) because I had subfolders in my S3 bucket this caused cloudfront to not know which file to serve.

Here is how to add a default root object in the cloudfront console:

1. Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon CloudFront console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/.
2. In the list of distributions in the top pane, select the distribution to update.
3. In the **Distribution Details pane**, on the **General** tab, click **Edit**.
4. In the **Edit Distribution** dialog box, in the **Default Root Object** field, enter the file name of the default root object.
5. Enter only the object name, for example, `index.html`. Do not add a / before the object name.
6. To save your changes, click **Yes, Edit**.

Comment: I have 2 distributions created from same Terraform module. One of them works even though "Default Root Object" is not set. If "Default Root Object" should be set to prevent the browser download the file, how come my other distribution works?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem. Upon changing my static website from http to https, all links wouldn't load pages, they instead downloaded empty (0kB) files named "download". Web console warned "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type binary/octet-stream". And when I checked in AWS S3, the HTML index files all had the correct MIME type text/html.

My solution was that CloudFront Distribution's "Origin Domain Name" needed to be copy-pasted from the S3 bucket's static-web-hosting endpoint property—not chosen from the dropdown list of options.

Answer (score 2):

If you changed the file settings, try clearing your cookies or opening it up in a new incognito window. It might be a cache-control issue (you could set the cache-control of the file to no-store)